# JAI ImageIO-core codecLib source

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jai

JAI ImageIO-core comes with a set of native codecs.  The codecs come bundled in a set of .so and .dll files.  Mainly  clib_jiio.dll  clib_jiio_sse2.dll  clib_jiio_util.dll.  I was able to find the source to mediaLib (mlib) but not the source for these codecs.  Anyone know where the source resides?  or if they are simply not open source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not open source. Read the [codecLib licence](http://java.net/projects/jai-imageio-core/sources/svn/content/trunk/LICENSE-codecLibJIIO.txt) for more information.

(However, caveat emptor: my answer is based on the best of my knowledge, and not on any inside information. I have no relation to `jai-imageio-core` nor codecLib.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to
[JAI and ImageIO for 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207145/jai-and-imageio-for-64-bit-windows/5293051#5293051)

Not open source and not plans to be and/or evolve.