# DICOM image to BufferedImage on Windows 64

Tags: java, bufferedimage, dicom, dcm4che

I need a way to convert a DICOM file into a BufferedImage (or if the dicom file is mult-frame then a set of BufferedImages) on Windows 64.  I am currently using dcm4che to do this, but am running into a problem because dcm4che uses JAI which thunks down to a native dll clib_jiio.dll which is not complied, and will not be compiled for Windows 64 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207145/jai-and-imageio-for-64-bit-windows)).  Does anyone know of an open source library that can do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several [DICOM plugins](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/index.html) are available for [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/).

Addendum: You might try the [64-bit version for Windows](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html) and the [built-in DICOM plugin](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html).

Comment: Which library in particular would you recommend?

Comment: Have you looked at [DICOM Import and Export](http://www.iftm.de/telemedizin/dcmimex.htm), which uses [`dcm4che`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to get away from.  As I said in my question "I am currently using dcm4che to do this, but am running into a problem because dcm4che uses JAI which thunks down to a native dll clib_jiio.dll which is not complied, and will not be compiled for Windows 64"

Comment: It appears that jimi uses oracle's jimi toolkit for jpeg, it is not clear what codec is used for jpeg 2000 (or if that is even supported). If memory is not an issues, you could use a 32 bit jvm on windows 64 bit with dcm4che2. If you must have the 64 bit jvm, you can configure use of the pure java codecs.   http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:general:which_file_formats_are_supported_by_imagej    http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Installation