# Setting jpg compression level with ImageIO in Java

Tags: java, jpeg, image-compression, javax.imageio

I'm using [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to save a `BufferedImage` as a jpeg file. 
In particular, I created the following Java function:

```
public static void getScreenShot(BufferedImage capture, Path folder, String filename) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(capture, "jpeg", new File(folder.toString()+"/"+filename+".jpg"));
        } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ScreenShotMaker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Likewise any image manipulation software, I wish to change the compression level of the jpeg file. However, I'm searching for this option that seems to be missing in `ImageIO`.

Can I set the compression level and how?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to use [`JPEGImageWriteParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html) and then save the image with [`ImageWriter.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write%28javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam%29). Before to write, set the output via [`ImageWriter.setOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#setOutput%28java.lang.Object%29).

Set the compression level as follows:

```
JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(1f);
```

Where `1f` is a float number that stands for 100% quality. Default value is *around 70%* if I don't remember wrong.

**EDIT**

Then, you have to do as follows to get an instance of an `ImageWriter`. There are two ways, a short and a long one (I keep both, just in case).

The  **short way** (suggested by [lapo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166524/lapo) in one comment) is:

```
final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
// specifies where the jpg image has to be written
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(
  new File(folder.toString() + "/" + filename + ".jpg")));

// writes the file with given compression level 
// from your JPEGImageWriteParam instance
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(capture, null, null), jpegParams);
```

or **longer way**

```
// use IIORegistry to get the available services
IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
// return an iterator for the available ImageWriterSpi for jpeg images
Iterator<ImageWriterSpi> services = registry.getServiceProviders(ImageWriterSpi.class,
                                                 new ServiceRegistry.Filter() {   
        @Override
        public boolean filter(Object provider) {
            if (!(provider instanceof ImageWriterSpi)) return false;

            ImageWriterSpi writerSPI = (ImageWriterSpi) provider;
            String[] formatNames = writerSPI.getFormatNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < formatNames.length; i++) {
                if (formatNames[i].equalsIgnoreCase("JPEG")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    },
   true);
//...assuming that servies.hasNext() == true, I get the first available service.
ImageWriterSpi writerSpi = services.next();
ImageWriter writer = writerSpi.createWriterInstance();

// specifies where the jpg image has to be written
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(
  new File(folder.toString() + "/" + filename + ".jpg")));

// writes the file with given compression level 
// from your JPEGImageWriteParam instance
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(capture, null, null), jpegParams);
```

Comment: `ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();`

Comment: Don't forget to close the FileImageOutputStream or dispose the ImageWriter

Comment: Does anyone know where I can reference what the exact default value is used?

Comment: @brad Use `jpegParams.getCompressionQuality()` without setting it. (You do still need to set `jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT)` first.) The default, for me at least, is `0.75`.

Comment: [Here is the documentation stating that the default value is 0.75.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html#JPEGImageWriteParam-java.util.Locale-)

Comment: You need to close the `FileImageOutputStream`

Answer (score 69):

A more succinct way is to get the `ImageWriter` directly from `ImageIO`:

```
ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(0.7f);

ImageOutputStream outputStream = createOutputStream(); // For example implementations see below
jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
jpgWriter.write(null, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
jpgWriter.dispose();
```

The call to `ImageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT)` is needed in order to explicitly set the compression's level (quality).

In `ImageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality()` `1.0f` is maximum quality, minimum compression, while `0.0f` is minimum quality, maximum compression.

`ImageWriter.setOutput` should be passed an [`ImageOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream.html). While the method accepts `Object`, according to documentation it's usually not supported:

> Use of a general `Object` other than an `ImageOutputStream` is intended for writers that interact directly with an output device or imaging protocol. The set of legal classes is advertised by the writer's service provider's `getOutputTypes` method; most writers will return a single-element array containing only `ImageOutputStream.class` to indicate that they accept only an `ImageOutputStream`.

Most cases should be handled by these two classes:

- [`FileImageOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/FileImageOutputStream.html) - an implementation of `ImageOutputStream` that writes its output directly to a `File` or `RandomAccessFile`.
- [`MemoryCacheImageOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.html) - an implementation of `ImageOutputStream` that writes its output to a regular `OutputStream`. Usually used with `ByteArrayOutputStream` (thanks for the tip, [@lmiguelmh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java/26319958?noredirect=1#comment42338976_26319958)!).

Comment: +1, I wonder why the more complicated one with the manual filtering was 1. posted, 2. accepted and 3. not improved for such a long time...

Comment: For those of you who don't want to write in disk: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); writer.setOutput(new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(baos)); ... baos.flush(); byte[] returnImage = baos.toByteArray(); baos.close();`

Comment: It surprises me that I came back to this same question, I can't edit my comment now. If you don't do what I said earlier and use `ByteArrayOutputStream` directly You will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal output type!`

Comment: @lmiguelmh: you can't edit your comment after 5 minutes since its creation. Also, I'll update my answer to address the issue with output streams, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I used `jpgWriter.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(path)))` as something went wrong with `FileImageOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

A more general method will be (from [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319958/10227958)) :

```
static void saveImage(BufferedImage image,File jpegFiletoSave,float quality) throws IOException{
    // save jpeg image with specific quality. "1f" corresponds to 100% , "0.7f" corresponds to 70%

        ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
        ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(quality);

        jpgWriter.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(jpegFiletoSave));
        IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
        jpgWriter.write(null, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
        jpgWriter.dispose();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found same method in my ancient library:

```
/**
 * Work method.
 * Reads the jpeg image in rendImage, compresses the image, and writes it back out to outfile.
 * JPEGQuality ranges between 0.0F and 1.0F, 0-lowest, 1-highest. ios is closed internally
 *
 * @param rendImage   [@link RenderedImage} instance with an Rendered Image
 * @param ios         {@link ImageOutputStream} instance,
 *                    note that it is disposed in this method
 * @param JPEGQuality float value for the JPEG compression quality (0..1(max))
 * @return {@code true} if image was successfully compressed
 *         else {@code false} on any error, e.g. bad (null) parameters
 */
public static boolean compressJpegFile( RenderedImage rendImage, ImageOutputStream ios, float JPEGQuality )
{
    if ( rendImage == null )
        return false;
    if ( ios == null )
        return false;
    if ( ( JPEGQuality <= 0.0F ) || ( JPEGQuality > 1.0F ) )
        return false;
    ImageWriter writer = null;
    try
    {

        // Find a jpeg writer
        Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName( "jpg" );
        if ( iter.hasNext() )
            writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();

        if ( writer == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "jpg writer not found by call to ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName( \"jpg\" )" );
        writer.setOutput( ios );

        // Set the compression quality
        ImageWriteParam iwparam = new MyImageWriteParam();
        iwparam.setCompressionMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT );
        iwparam.setCompressionQuality( JPEGQuality );
        //      float res = iwparam.getCompressionQuality();

        // Write the image
        writer.write( null, new IIOImage( rendImage, null, null ), iwparam );

        return true;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( writer != null )
            writer.dispose();
        // Cleanup
        try
        {
            ios.flush();
            ios.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u require a byte[] output see a modified version of @user_3pij answer below:

```
    private static byte[] compressImageToByteArray(BufferedImage image, float quality)
        throws IOException {
    // save jpeg image with specific quality. "1f" corresponds to 100% , "0.7f" corresponds to
    // 70%

    ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
    ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bos);
    jpgWriter.setOutput(ios);
    IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
    jpgWriter.write(null, outputImage, jpgWriteParam);
    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
    jpgWriter.dispose();
    return result;
}
```