# Change the theme of computer while taking robot screenshot

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, awtrobot

I want to take continuos screenshots using robot and transfer it to the other computer.I am using socket for transfereing images.But it is very slow.So i want to reduce the quality and size of the images.So Like teamviewer while taking screenshots how can i change the theme of the system to basic.

Comment: So you want to resize an image and alter the theme of an operating system that you haven't named. This question is rather vague and confusing at the moment. Why is the transfer rate slow? Are you sure you are doing it right? There isn't any code to try to understand or anything. It's just a load of words...

Comment: Resize an image in java: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/

Comment: i don't want to resize the image.Just want to change the color depth of the computer from which i am taking screenshots.(i.e while taking remote desktop using MSTSC, the client computer's color is changing.like wise..)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the theme to basic to disable visual effects which in turn would result in a reduced color palette and more uniform colored areas of the screen, resulting in reduced sizes of the images.

Instead of changing the theme of the computer, I recomend you to try using low quality alone, by using (for example) a JPEG format, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java).
Also, consider using the GIF format, which I think results in no distortion of the image as the JPEG, but just the palette reduction.

Also, you have an alternative library to manipulate images, [Commons Imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/gettingstarted.html), which seems to be quite powerful, but I've never used it myself.