# ImageIO save picture and the size gets small

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I try to save a picture by using the class ImageIO, but I have found a problem that the size of the picture will small. The code is like this:

```
public class SeamCarving {
    static String path="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/h4/01.jpg";
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        File file1=new File(path);
        System.out.println(file1.length());
        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(file1);
        File file2=new File("d:/02.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",file2);
        image.flush();
        System.out.println(file2.length());
    }
}
```

After the operation, I found the size is 4788268 and 1529534.
So I can't understand why the size of the picture is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it with `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` classes:

```
public class SeamCarving {
    static String pathFrom = "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/h4/01.jpg";
    static String pathTo = "d:/02.jpg";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file1 = new File(pathFrom);
        File file2 = new File(pathTo);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathFrom);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathTo);

        System.out.println(file1.length());
        int buffSize;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((buffSize = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffSize);
        }
        System.out.println(file2.length());

        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this way will not change the size of the picture, but I need to use the ImageIO class, because I am writing the algorithm of seam carving  which will related to the operation of the pixel. So I need to use this way to save the picture.

Comment: I see, then please read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273672/image-size-getting-decreased-after-converting-it-into-byte-using-bufferedimage). Output image compresses with 0.75 ratio, so the size reduces accordingly.

Comment: oh, I see.  Thank you for your answer!