# Java Byte array to image file creation results a rotated upside down image file

Tags: java, arrays, image, javax.imageio

I am just reading an image file as byte array and writing it in another directory as image file using `BufferedImage` like shown in the link :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-Byte-Array-to-Image-in-java

But for some image files the created new image file is rotated upside down. Majority of the images works fine.

And also created new images size are increased compared to the source image.
What i am missing here ?

Comment: Why? Why not just copy the bytes?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne  yes it will work... but i 've created a method to store byte array as image file. For testing purpose only.. i read a image file as byte array and passing to that method...
while doing that.. this scenario happened.

Comment: If it's for testing purposes only there is no purpose at all. You don't have to do this. Solution: don't. But if you're surprised that an image in an unstated format ended up as a different size in JPEG format, again I would ask why?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne. in testing i am just ensuring that the same image with same size (i mean exactly the same) copied through the byte array format.. i hope it is purposeful... i am just worried about the same format (jpg) file copy process as mentioned in question (through byte array[]) results an upside down image (for some images only (weird case)).. and also size is increased....

Comment: This just isn't so. You are saving as a JPEG. This implies adaptive compression. If you run the same image through the JPEG algorithm several times you will get a different result every time. This is not something that needs testing, or explaining.