# Why does reading and writing a JPEG with Java ImageIO reduce the file size?

Tags: java, flashair

I am using Java's [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to read contents from my FlashAir 32Gb (2nd gen) and to write them to my local hard drive. I can read and save the files, but I noticed that the ones in the hard drive are much smaller than the originals in the SD Card. Any ideas of why this is happening?
This is the code that I use:

```
URL imageURL = new URL("http://192.168.0.1/DCIM/100__TSB/IMG_0001.JPG");
File dest = new File("/home/me/Pictures/FlashAir/IMG_0001.JPG");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", dest);
```

The images save to the local hard drive are fine, but they are about 1/3 of the original size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code isn't just copying (reading and saving) files. It's decoding the images, and then re-encoding them at the default JPEG compression rate (which, judging by the [`JPEGImageWriteParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html) documentation, is 0.75).

If you want to change the compression level, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java).

If you're trying to copy the files exactly, don't use `ImageIO` at all.