# Significant jpeg quality loss after downloading and base64 encoding

Tags: java, compression, base64, jpeg, loss

My app downloads a Facebook user's jpeg profile picture and base64 encodes it. When decoding it, the resulting jpeg quality and size is significantly reduced. How do I avoid this?

Here is the way I'm downloading/encoding:

```
// Download the profile picture.
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://facebook-profile-pic"));
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", bos);

// Base64 encode it.
String imageData = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bos.toByteArray()));
```

When I take the value of imageData and decode it, the image is way smaller than the one at the original download URL.

Comment: `new String(byteArray)` is unreliable, as it uses the underlying system’s default charset to encode the bytes.  If that charset is UTF-8 or some ISO-8859 charsets, it will work for Base64-encoded bytes, but if it’s anything else, your data will be corrupted.  Use `String imageData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());` instead.

Comment: JPEG is a lossless file format, and ImageIO uses a specific quality when writing. For higher quality and/or lossless you need to specify the quality explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Encoding to/from Base64 is completely lossless. The quality loss happens probably when you save it. To prevent that, use an `ImageWriter` directly (`ImageIO.write` already uses it internally, but gives you no control over the settings):

```
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
writer.setOutput(bos);

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(1.0F); // Highest quality

writer.write(image, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

Also, it might be that you already download a low quality image depending on what API you use.

Answer (score 0):

> When decoding it, the resulting jpeg quality and size is significantly reduced

JPEG is a lossy file format, and `ImageIO` uses a default lossy compression metric when writing jpg file. For higher quality (or lossless) you need to explicitly handle the compression quality yourself though a [JPEGImageWriteParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html).

```
//create the params    
JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(1f);//set compression quality
```

See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java) for writing to files. To write in memory, you will need to use [MemoryCacheImageOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.html)

```
//write to output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MemoryCacheImageOutputStream ios = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(bos);
final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
writer.setOutput(ios);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), jpegParams);
```