# Convert PNG to JPEG, Using Compression Quality, Why Inverted colors?

Tags: java, png, jpeg, javax.imageio

I have low information about the image files.

To be able to convert PNG to JPEG in Java, at first I have used below code part to convert PNG to JPEG: inverted

**Code Part 1)**

```
BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImageFile.getWidth(), bufferedImageFile.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImageFile, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
File retTempFile = MakeupFileUtil.createTempFile(fileName);
ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg", retTempFile);
return retTempFile;
```

This accomplishes the task very well but the output quality is lower than the original PNG image quality(let's say PNG quality is 100 but JPEG quality is 75)

Then, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108301/1201725), I tried below code part which uses **"Compression Quality"**:

**Code Part 2)**

```
JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(1f);
final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(jpegFile));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImageFile, null, null), jpegParams);
```

But this time, converted JPEG file got inverted colors.

Source Image (PNG):
[image: source png image]

Image After Code Part 2 (JPEG):
[image: part 2 code result jpeg]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and write `newBufferedImage` and not `bufferedImageFile` on "Code part 2".

So change this line to be:

```
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(newBufferedImage, null, null), jpegParams);
```

If you try and write a PNG image in JPEG format your going to end up with weird results.