# Java AWT text produces artifacts

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to draw some text on some plain color background, and I'm getting some artifacts around the text.  Is there a way to get clean writing?

```
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 400,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.fillRect(0,0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    Font font = new Font ("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40);

    AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform, true, true);

    TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("Hello World!", font, frc);
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    layout.draw(g2d, 100, 100);

    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("testDirtyText.jpg"));
```

It's producing some artifacts as shown here:
[image]

Any advice around any other aspect of this would be appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Err, what artifacts; sorry, but I only see a blue rectangle with some white text; and nothing that looks "out of order"?!

Comment: The artifacts are just around the edges of the text.  It's because of JPEG compression quality issues.  @Boann pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether you're referring to aliasing artifacts or JPEG compression artifacts. To fix the former, add:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html for more rendering options.

To fix the latter, save as a PNG instead:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
```

Or if you really need a JPEG, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java) about setting the JPEG quality level.

Comment: Thanks Boann!  It turned out to be the JPEG compression level.  I did a separate search on how to set it and ended up in the same link you sent (didn't see the link at first).  I thought I already tried it with PNG before, but it looks like I did the PNG before I did the solid color block, so I didn't see the PNG vs JPEG issue then.  Setting the compression quality to 90% fixed the issue.