# Should I convert BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, rgb, rgba

I am working on image interpolation for which I am using bi-cubic interpolation to double the resolution of image in java using `AffinedTransformOp`.I used `BufferedImage` of `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` while doing up-scaling. When I tried to save back my upscale image using `ImageIO.write` then I found that openjdk does not support `jpeg` encoding for `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` so I converted this up-scaled image from `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` to `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`. When I saved it in folder then found that the memory taken by this upscale image is way less(about half time) than the memory taken by original image.

So I assume that the original(input) image is represented by four channels `ARGB` while upscale(output) image is taking 3 channels `RGB` and that's why getting less memory.

Now my question is that should I use this conversion? 
 
Is there some information that is getting lost?
Does quality of image remains same?

P.S: I've read from the documentation of `ImageIO` that when we convert `ARGB` to `RGB` than the alpha value gets premultiplied  to `RGB` values and I think it should not affect the quality of the image.

Comment: Was the input image also in jpeg? Jpeg doesn't support an alpha channel. It's more likely that you use a (much) lower quality when you write the image than what was used in the original image.

Comment: Yes the original image is in jpeg. And I wrote back the image in jpeg.

Comment: You'l probably want to check out this question to find out how to set the compression/image quality level when you write out the JPEG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and hope to share my answer. Actually the type of my original image was Grayscale and the color space of my original image was grey (meaning only one channel with 8 bits) with quality of 90.
Problem arised when I used `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` for the upscaling instead of using `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`. Secondly when you try to save this image in a file in jpeg format `ImageIO.write` uses compression of 75 by default so the image size will get small. You should use the compression factor which suits you or you should save it in PNG format.
 You can view information about your image by using `identify -verbos image.jpg` in linux and can see the color space, image type and quality etc
You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java) to see how to set  your compression quality manually in `ImageIO`.