# Set ImageWriter output to ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, image-processing, servlets, javax.imageio

I'm trying to compress images with this method: [Setting jpg compression level with ImageIO in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108234/setting-jpg-compression-level-with-imageio-in-java).

The solution works fine, but I use ObjectOutputStream instead of FileImageOutputStream, when I set the ObjectOutputStream as the writer output I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal output type!` exception. I need to use ObjectOutputStream.

This works perfectly  `ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outstream);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [`ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outstream);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-), the method will invoke [`ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageOutputStream-java.lang.Object-) and pass the result to the `ImageWriter`. When you call [`setOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#setOutput(java.lang.Object)) directly, you must do that yourself.

```
ImageWriter w = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
w.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputStream));
w.write(image);
```